# How sort according to given order and calculation 1st document with second one in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get which members not present when state change and which member is present.

My given array for state order like:

```
[{order:1,text:'CS'}, {order:2,text:'IP'}, {order:3,text:'AC'}]
```

so I want to sort according to this array want to perform some operation with each pare of documents

My documents like:

```
{
  "count" : 2,
  "state" : "CS",
  "members" : [
    {
      "email" : "builuu1998@gmail.com",
      "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z")
    },
    {
      "email" : "bactv.hn@gmail.com",
      "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
    }
  ]
},
{
  "count" : 1,
  "state" : "AC",
  "members" : [
    {
      "email" : "builuu1998@gmail.com",
      "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z")
    }
  ]
},
  {
    "count" : 3,
    "state" : "IP",
    "members" : [
      {
        "email" : "builuu1998@gmail.com",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z")
      },
      {
        "email" : "bactv.hn@gmail.com",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
      },
      {
        "email" : "abc.hn@gmail.com",
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
      }
    ]
  }
```

So I want to know which members are not present from one state to another state and which members are present .

In my exam 1st state to 2nd state means (CS - IP): present 2 members and not present 1 member

```
{
"state": "CS_IP",
"present": [
  {
    "email" : "builuu1998@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z")
  },
  {
    "email" : "bactv.hn@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
  }
],

"notPresent": [
  {
    "email" : "abc.hn@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
  }
]
}
```

and 2nd state to 3rd state means (IP - AC): present 1 members and not present 2 member

```
{"state": "IP_AC",
"present": [
  {
    "email" : "builuu1998@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z")
  }
],

"notPresent": [
  {
    "email" : "bactv.hn@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
  },
  {
    "email" : "abc.hn@gmail.com",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z")
  }
]}
```

How can I achieve this using `aggregate` query because I need some aggregate operation after this stage complete

Answer (score 0):

You can perform one aggregation request per "couple" of state like this for `["IP", "AC"]` :

```
db.exams.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "state": {
            $in: ["IP", "AC"]
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": 1,
        "group1": { "$first": "$members" },
        "group2": { "$last": "$members" }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "present": { "$setIntersection": ["$group1", "$group2"] },
        "notPresent": {
            $setUnion: [
                { "$setDifference": ["$group1", "$group2"] },
                { "$setDifference": ["$group2", "$group1"] }
            ]
        }
    }
}])
```

Note that this will only work for 2 elements to match (here `["IP", "AC"]`) since we have to create two new fields `group1` & `group2` to `$setIntersection` and `$setDifference` (as there is no `$group` with `$setIntersection` and `$setDifference`)

The query above will give :

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "present": [
        { "email": "builuu1998@gmail.com", "date": ISODate("2016-12-24T03:39:05.720Z") }
    ],
    "notPresent": [
        { "email": "abc.hn@gmail.com", "date": ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z") },
        { "email": "bactv.hn@gmail.com", "date": ISODate("2016-12-25T02:32:48.698Z") }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have about 20 state and I want to get all information in a single query. any another idea? @bertrand-martel